# How to get cities list from multiple lat, lng list?

Tags: php, reverse, geocoding

I maintain lat,lng in DB every 2 minuts when person is traveling. so i have all lat, lng where they travelled.
now i want unique cities list from those lat, longs.
i know very well that Reverse Geocoding can be done the job

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=APIKEY

and its work good, but i can not pass lat,lng one by one and get list of address.
due to i have lotsof lat, long data  like for one person it near about 1000 lat,lng. and i have 700 persons. so it is a big data to process.

i want only unique cities name.

Comment: _"for one person it near about 1000 lat,lng. and i have 700 persons"_ - and you need this for all of them, at the same time?

Comment: You should probably cache results on your end. Round those lat/long values to a reasonable precision - and then store the API call results on your end. Little sense in hammering the API a second time with coordinates that are only ever so slightly "off" those you already checked, that is not suddenly going to result in a completely different city.

Comment: According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674), two decimals places of precision represent about 1.1km, so if you are looking at just cities you can hopefully use just that, especially if you are storing every two minutes. I would think this would drop your count considerably. After that, queue these on a server and have it resolve these according to rate-limiting rules

Comment: @CBroe yes i need those all lat,lng. i draw path wherever they are go.